# Sqlite3 value in Ruby Script not working as string

Tags: ruby, authentication, sqlite

I am trying to create a user-auth system and have run into a problem. In this code, I am trying to check if a certain value matches another value in the same row. It prints but does not work as a string when I set it equal to another string.

```
    db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS auth(id int, name text, password text)")

    db.execute("INSERT INTO auth(id, name, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", [1, 'Bugs', 'Carrots'])    


   t = db.execute("SELECT password FROM auth WHERE name = 'Bugs'") 

   if t == 'Carrots'
     puts "yes"
   end

   #i am trying to print yes to the console
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're creating an authentication system, please **encrypt all user passwords** and **never store them as plain-text**. At the absolute least use a password-specific hash like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: Thank you tadman, i will check out bcrypt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting back an array representing the list of matches, although in this case there's only one row returned.  Furthermore, the row itself is an array of values, although in this case the row will be an array of only one value.  So you should be comparing `t[0][0]` rather than just `t`

You could use the function `db.get_first_value` instead to simplify this.

(This assumes that `name` is unique; you probably want to use a `UNIQUE` constraint in the database schema for both `id` and `name`.)

(And, yes, you should take @tadman's warning to heart.)

So here's a minimally altered version of the code you posted above (*without* the suggested improvements) that gives the desired result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sqlite3'

db = SQLite3::Database.new(':memory:')

db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS auth(id int, name text, password text)")

db.execute("INSERT INTO auth(id, name, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)",
           [1, 'Bugs', 'Carrots'])


t = db.execute("SELECT password FROM auth WHERE name = 'Bugs'")

if t[0][0] == 'Carrots'
  puts "yes"
end
```

Comment: Thanks varro. I tried it out but it still did not print yes. I am probably doing something wrong, Could you post a sample of the correct code?

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work for you, but I will expand my answer above to give a complete example.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I used db.get_first_value incorrectly but this method worked perfectly.

Comment: @AliKesserwani Glad to have helped.  Please consider hitting the check button to accept the answer.